# How to continually run a Spring Batch job

Tags: spring-batch

What is the best way to continually run a Spring Batch job? Do we need to write a shell file which loops and starts the job at predefined intervals? Or is there a way within Spring Batch itself to configure a job so that it repeats at either

1) pre-defined intervals

2) after the completion of each run

Thanks

Comment: Use a scheduler (quartz for example)

Comment: if you don't want to use any 3rd party framework writing a perl script to restart job at specific intervals is the best option

Comment: For clarification: can the the quartz scheduler being integrated into Spring Batch so that is is intelligent enough to re-run a job, or is it necessary to do this from Unix

Answer (score 3):

If you want to launch your jobs periodically, you can combine [Spring Scheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) and Spring Batch. Here is a concrete example : [Spring Scheduler + Batch Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/).

If you want to re-launch your job continually (Are you sure !), You can configure a [Job Listener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html) on your job. Then, through the method `jobListener.afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)` you can relaunch your job.

Answer (score 1):

Id did something like this for importing emails, so i have to check it periodically

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class ImportBillingFromEmailBatchRunner
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportBillingFromEmailBatchRunner.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ImportBillingFromEmailBatchRunner.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    BillingEmailCronService billingEmailCronService()
    {
        return new BillingEmailCronService();
    }

}
```

So the BillingEmailCronService takes care of the continuation:

```
public class BillingEmailCronService
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BillingEmailCronService.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private @Qualifier(BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER)
    Step fetchBillingFromEmailsStep;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void run()
    {
       LOG.info("Procesando correos con facturas...");
       try
       {
          Job job = createNewJob();
          JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
          jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
       }catch(...)
       {
          //Handle each exception
       }
    }
}
```

Implement your `createNewJob` logic and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

one easy way would be configure cron job from Unix which will run application at specified interval